# Swift - UITableView cell.detailTextLable.text is not visible

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have been trying all the methods from StackOverFlow to get this working but I had no luck.

The UITableView `cell.textLabel` is displaying correctly but not the `cell.detailTextLable`

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 3
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cellIdentifier = "cell"

    var cell : UITableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier) as? UITableViewCell
    if cell == nil {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
    }

    cell!.textLabel?.text = "hello"
    cell!.detailTextLabel?.text = "world"
    return cell!
}
```

I noticed that in other tutorials the last 3 cell lines did not have the optionals on `textLabel` or `detailTextLabel`, but XCode throws me errors if I don't have the optionals. Maybe that is an indication of an error somewhere else?

EDIT: How I created the actual UITableView

```
var dataTable : UITableView = UITableView()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    dataTable.frame = CGRectMake(0, 300, 200, 200)
    dataTable.delegate = self
    dataTable.dataSource = self

    dataTable.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

    self.view.addSubview(dataTable)
}
```

Comment: Did you set the cell to be the "subtitle" type in IB?

Comment: @rdelmar I didn't use the IB to create the cell, the cell was created in the code above.

Or do you mean the table itself? I created that by


`var dataTable : UITableView = UITableView()`
`dataTable.frame = CGRectMake(0, 300, 200, 200)`
`dataTable.delegate = self`
`dataTable.dataSource = self`
`dataTable.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")`
  
`self.view.addSubview(dataTable)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you register the UITableViewCell class, you are guaranteed to get a cell, and it will be the basic cell that doesn't have a detailTextLabel. Because of this, your "if cell == nil" clause will never run. Just delete the register class statement, and your code should work correctly.